# Drupal 7 User Like node

Tags: drupal-7, user-profile, drupal-nodes, drupal-field-api

I have been working with Drupal 7. I have a scenario where user like a particular node. If user likes the node it will increment 1 in the node field which is reference by a user by passing it UID. Now can any one give me clear documentation regarding this or there is any tutorial regarding referencing node field by UID.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want but are you looking for a contributor module like https://drupal.org/project/nodevote ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) modules achieves this functionally. It even have integration with Views and Tokens making your life much easier :)